# error with php file - insert query

Tags: php

I'm having problems with insert details to mysql server. 
This is the code (a simple one):

```
<?php
//Input posted data.
$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
$Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
$Date = $_POST["Date"];
$Mail = $_POST["Mail"];
$Pass = $_POST["Pass"];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',"");

//Check if the connection was opened, if not prompt the error to the page.
if ($conn)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select the data base.
mysqli_select_db("club",$conn);

//Set the character set to utf-8 to allow hebrew.
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");   

//SQL query - user Details 
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'customers' (Fname, Lname, Mail, Date, Pass) 
VALUES('$Fname','$Lname','$Mail','$Date','$Pass');

//Run SQL query
$results = mysqli_query($query) or die (mysql_error());


//Close the SQL connection.
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

I'm getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Contact.php on line 36 <--- The last line

Can really use your help.

thanks in advance,
Jason.

Comment: you have not close the query  $sql  string missing " at the end

Comment: That's it...and also you code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Missing " at the end of $sql variable.

Comment: A proper ide would help identifying this

Comment: `mysql_error()` also wont help you with `mysqli`.

Comment: You also are using `mysql_` syntax with `mysqli`.

Answer (score 2):

$results=mysqli_query($sql);

you have given $query instead of $sql

Comment: Good spot! Though

Comment: (Voted up so you can add this as a comment.)

Comment: I want to thank you all guys with your help. I appreciate it. thanks again.

Comment: Also thanks JasonB. for assist.